# Win32 Draw a Dragging Rectangle

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdi

I am trying to draw a rectangle as you left click on a point and then drag across , while your dragging across the rectangle gets form to show you a preview of how the rectangle will look . This works fine except when I drag back into a smaller rectangle the old rectangles still remain.

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

    if(painting)
    {



            HPEN greenPen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,255,0));
            SelectObject(hdc,greenPen);
            Rectangle(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }


    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    painting=true;
    x1=LOWORD(lParam);
    y1=HIWORD(lParam);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL ,false);
    break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:



        x2=LOWORD(lParam);
        y2=HIWORD(lParam);

        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL ,false);


    break;
case WM_LBUTTONUP:

    painting=false;
    break;
```

Comment: While you still have the mouse button down?

Comment: yes while I still have the mouse down, I know why this is happening but is there any way I can get rid of those old rectangles? Thanks

Comment: Use InvalidateRect with TRUE as the last parameter

Comment: Is it the real code? If yes, then there are problems with GDI objects. You can run out of GDI objects very soon if you do not destroy the greenPen. Also, it is a good idea to store the previous object after SelectObject and return it back to the DC after you've done.

Comment: It's not the real code no, but thanks. I have set it to true but that means that as soon as I draw another rectangle, the old rectangle will get deleted . How do I store the previous object? ( rectangle)

Answer (score 2):

@user1788175 - just use a RECT struct. When the drawing starts, you set the left & top members to the x,y pos of the mouse. When the mouse is released, set the right,bottom members. Swap left,right if necessary, to ensure that left

Here's some code ripped from a class I wrote to deal with with selection rectangles. You can ignore the normalize code - it just converts the pixel coordinates to ones in the range [0..1], so I can draw the selection on a scaled-down version of the image, yet still select the same region if the image is shown at a different scale. My images were 4944x6992, so I had to display a scaled-down version of them.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK cSelBoxImg::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT mappedRect, tmpRect, myRect;
    HBRUSH myBrush;
    BITMAP bm;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC mDC;
    HBITMAP tmpBmp;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if (bMouseSelectionEnabled)
        {
            bRubberBanding = true;
            mouseClickDownPos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
            mouseClickDownPos.y = HIWORD(lParam);

            curMousePos = mouseClickDownPos;
            selectionRect.left = min(curMousePos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
            selectionRect.right = max(curMousePos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
            selectionRect.top = min(curMousePos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);
            selectionRect.bottom = max(curMousePos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);
            normalizeSelRect();
            InvalidateRect(mHwnd, NULL, isBkgTransparent);
            PostMessage(GetParent(hWnd),  WM_COMMAND, GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd), (LPARAM)hWnd);
        }
        return 1;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        if (bMouseSelectionEnabled)
            if (bRubberBanding)
            {
                bRubberBanding = false;
                mouseClickUpPos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
                mouseClickUpPos.y = HIWORD(lParam);

                selectionRect.left = min(mouseClickUpPos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
                selectionRect.right = max(mouseClickUpPos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
                selectionRect.top = min(mouseClickUpPos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);
                selectionRect.bottom = max(mouseClickUpPos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);

                normalizeSelRect();
                InvalidateRect(mHwnd, NULL, isBkgTransparent);
                PostMessage(GetParent(hWnd),  WM_COMMAND, GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd), (LPARAM)hWnd);
            }
        return 1;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (bMouseSelectionEnabled)
            if (bRubberBanding)
            {
                curMousePos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
                curMousePos.y = HIWORD(lParam);

                selectionRect.left = min(curMousePos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
                selectionRect.right = max(curMousePos.x, mouseClickDownPos.x);
                selectionRect.top = min(curMousePos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);
                selectionRect.bottom = max(curMousePos.y, mouseClickDownPos.y);
                //                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
                //RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW);
                normalizeSelRect();
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, false);
                PostMessage(GetParent(hWnd),  WM_COMMAND, GetDlgCtrlID(hWnd), (LPARAM)hWnd);
                //       printf("Message posted\n");
            }
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:

        mDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &tmpRect);
    //        GetObject(mBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        mappedRect.left = mLeft * tmpRect.right;
        mappedRect.right = mRight * tmpRect.right;
        mappedRect.top = mTop * tmpRect.bottom;
        mappedRect.bottom = mBottom * tmpRect.bottom;

        displayImage();
        if  (mBmp) drawRect(mDC, mappedRect, RGB(0,0,255));
        DeleteObject(tmpBmp);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        return 0;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        if (isBkgTransparent)
        {
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &myRect);
            myBrush = (HBRUSH) GetWindowLong(hWnd, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND);
            FillRect((HDC)wParam, &myRect, myBrush);
            printf("background cleared\n");
        }
        return true;

    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        SetCursor(mCursor);
        return true;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I just stumbled upon this post since I am searching examples of dragging image with the mouse. I assume that the above is from production code so I want to help you by pointing out some crucial mistakes: You **must** handle `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` and move your "cleanup" code there. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359/Capturing-the-Mouse) sums it up well. Also, you need to adapt your code in mouse button handlers for multiple monitors. Use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` instead of `LOWORD` and `HIWORD`, just reread the docs. +1

Comment: Hiya. :) - That was the hope at the time I wrote it, but we ended up just buying some software instead. It was from a OMR software - it was to be used to create a 'template' of a university attendance sheet, such that 100 or so A4 pages per day could be scanned, deskewed and then recognize the student-id barcode and the checkbox indicating the time present in the class. We ended up just going with Remark Office OMR. Thanks for the link my friend, it shall serve me well in the future,I hope. Not sure if I got a msg from you a month or two ago, sorry if so - its been a rough couple months. :-(

Comment: I am struggling to implement listview autoscroll feature while dragging and dropping. I am trying to phrase the question but have some problems with it. Perhaps we can meet here on chat to discuss. I am also trying to implement something like map viewer but have got stuck. *Not sure if I got a msg from you a month or two ago* I am busy, but have posted here some questions though... Hopefully we can speak on chat to catch up... Best regards :)

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember. I'll have a look at the open questions from your profile page and see what, if anything, I can do. The only way I know of initiating a chat here is to write too many back-and-forth comments. I'm not familiar with map-viewer - is it geographical maps, or data-structure maps?